# Link from markdown file to php class

Tags: php, doxygen

I'm documenting a php project with doxygen. Now I want to put a link in a markdown file, that targets to a php class: `\mynamespace\service\Config`. How do I have to write that link?

(The markdown file is transformed by doxygen into a html file and doxygen should be able to create such a link.)

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/markdown.html (found it < 1sec in google).

Comment: Sure. What is the solution, you think this page describes?